# Connectivity problem on LG Viper LS840 just updated to Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, connection-issues, lg-viper

MY LG LS840 (Viper) is not opening Play Store after it updated to Ice Cream Sandwich  yesterday.  My emails are not sending either: they stay in my outbox.  How do I fix this?  I pulled the battery and it's still not working right.

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset?

Comment: UPDATE:  Apparently my phone is LTE and that's not available where I live, so my cell was working overtime trying to connect and it caused an issue with my data connectivity once I updated to ICS.  It took 4 days, a replacement phone, and 5 Sprint techs before SOMEONE figured it out!  I updated my profile, PRL, and clicked off LTE/CDMA to just CDMA and all is running perfectly!  GEEZ!  I hope my trouble helps anyone else with this particular phone.

Comment: you should post this as an answer to your own question...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my phone is LTE and that's not available where I live, so my cell was working overtime trying to connect and it caused an issue with my data connectivity when I updated to ICS.

I updated my profile, PRL, and clicked off LTE/CDMA to just CDMA and all is running perfectly!